# How comparing JavaScript timestamp and a number possible?

Tags: javascript, html

How comparing a timestamp with a simple number possible?
*I know its not a good idea to compare a number and an object's method*
 but what i am asking is the reason for why number in can be compared in cases like:

```js
var a = new Date().getTime();

if (a > 1700) {
  alert(a + " is bigger than 1700");
} else {
  alert(a + " is not bigger than 1700")
};
```

Which gives result:

[image: Output Alert Box]

Comment: Your code does not produce the output you describe in your question.

Comment: Hi, I converted your code to a snippet so you can run it. After your edit fixing the `<`, there is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You made a little mistake in your statement... Your now looking if a is lower than 1700, so change your operator...

```
var a= new Date().getTime();

//If a is bigger...
if(a>1700){
    alert(a+ " is bigger than 1700");
}
else
    { alert(a+" is not bigger than 1700") };
```

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing that out. And, does it mean it can be compared with a number without any unexpected result?

Comment: Yes, it can... typeof new Date().getTime() is number

Comment: @Jonas W: Equality checks means '===' check?

Comment: @johnny in case you would do `new Date() < 12` that would work without problems, but `new Date() === 12` wont work, but as you use `getTime` its not a matter at all

Answer (score 0):

When you log `a+" is not bigger than 1700"` it has entered the `else` branch, so `a < 1700` is false. That is right as the huge number is *not* smaller than 1700. I gues syou want to swap `<` with `>`

Answer (score 0):

Wrong logical operator.
Clearly,

```
a<1700
```

is false, hence the  else statement
You have written wrong alerts